# Problems with AppDomains element in Excel Add-in task pane XML manifest

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have no app domains to be specified with `<AppDomain/>` child element inside the `<AppDomains/>` element in an Excel Add-in task pane manifest. I cannot leave an unspecified `<AppDomain/>` as this generates an error at validation:

> Package acceptance validation error: XML Schema Validation Error Error found during XML Schema validation. Code: The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1:AppDomain' element is invalid - The value '' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1:LongString' - The actual length is less than the MinLength value. Line: 16 Column: 10

I probably cannot remove `<AppDomain/>` and leave `<AppDomains/>` given that [the latter has property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/00e4ee5d-2eb8-47f2-9008-8beb6ff45189) `minOccurs="1"`.

I've found [this manifest example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#manifest-v11-xml-file-examples-and-schemas) where `<AppDomains/>`and `<AppDomain/>` are omitted. However, I don't know if this is an official way of doing it. I did not find documentation describing if `<AppDomains/>` is an obligatory element for Office task pane manifests and what should be done if there's nothing to be listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<AppDomains>` is not mandatory. You can find a list of required elements here: [Manifest required elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1#required-elements). Also, the official XSD for the manifest is here: [MS-OWEMXML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/00e4ee5d-2eb8-47f2-9008-8beb6ff45189).

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense